# documentation, pointers on TMyTable.Open in MyDAC

Tags: mysql, delphi, mydac

I am learning Devart's [mydac](http://www.devart.com/mydac/) Data Access Components and I have few question I have not been able to resolve through online searches and the documentations. In the code examples, I see invocation of `TMyTable.Open` but I could not find the description in `TMyTable` class or its inheritance path. I would like to as if anyone can point me to the documentation of this method and whether it has any relationship to `TDBGrid` class.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found out that the `Open` procedure is declared in `TDataSet` but I still can not find any documentation on what it does and how it does it. I know that if you're working with an SQL query, it gets invoked implicitly when you call `Execute`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TDataSet.Open` is generally used to get a data cursor back from the database.

In order to use a `TDBGrid` you need to connect it to the `TDataSet` (In your case a `TMyTable`) through a `TDataSource`.

On the other hand `TMyTable.Execute` will only run your SQL code on the server and not retrieve any data (except for some info on the affected rows).

You normally use `Execute` for `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, etc and `Open` for `SELECT` statements.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, a F1 keystroke while the caret is over a SQLQuery1.Open; brings the help in the DB.TDataSet.Open article, which in turn gave me a (broken) link to the current DocWiki Page.  Far from perfect, but good enough to get basic information.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TDataSet.Open